# How can Tilly recognize this ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-discovery

During Star Trek Discovery, Season 3 Episode 5:

When Discovery enters the Federation field, Tilly recognises Voyager “J” version and they make a remark about 11 generation of the ship.

According to Wikipedia, Discovery is set on 2255 while Voyager was launched on 2371. So, How is that possible?

Is it a goof on the production of the series or is there any in universe explanation? I seem to recall Voyager (the one in the series) was the first of its class but maybe it had a designation “C” or something already.

Comment: She's just reading the name and guessing based on some other ships she evidently already knows about that used letters for iterations.

Comment: She's only impressed by the J.

Comment: Also previously the galaxy class Yamato was NCC-1305-E before production wanted only the Enterprise to have honorary letter registrations - so when it appeared for real and exploded it had NCC-71807 (or other numbers its complicated production errors) The Defiant on DS9 being the only canon non Enterprise to have a letter after that.

Comment: Like @lucasbachmann said she was only impressed by the number of iterations.

Comment: I think the question needs clarification. Are you asking how she knew the _Voyager J_ was the result of upgrades?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it is inaccurate.

Comment: I was under the impression that Tilly recognised the ship designation itself (Voyager) not just the fact that it was a J

Comment: @lucasbachmann Defiant did not have a letter I'm aware of. Source?

Comment: @T.J.L. when the Sao Paulo was renamed as the second Defiant the -A was implicit.  Note at the time they were recycling cgi and the Defiant was going between NX and NCC so visual canon isn't reliable.  But I suppose you are correct.   However it is understood that the Enterprise-A was renamed in the exact same manner as the Defiant.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Understood by whom? Source?

Comment: In universe the earliest instance I can think of is when Daniels tells Archer about the Enterprise-J

Answer (score 1):

The assumption here is that Starfleet had named other ships with letters by this time. Discovery left in [2258](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2258), and the [Enterprise A was commissioned in 2286](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2286). That's only 28 years.

Furthermore, the Federation had lost a lot of ships in the [Klingon War](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation-Klingon_War_(2256-57)). The letter designations were clearly for "famous" ships and it's quite possible there were one or two "famous" ships already in service by the time Discovery leaves.

In other words, it's not unreasonable to assume they had seen a letter ship and knew the significance.